# What is the correct syntax for a 301 redirect using {QUERY_STRING} in .htaccess when a URL has multiple parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve using this example URL:

```
URL: http://www.example.com/directory1/search/index.php?pagesize=10&keywords=illinois&ord=az&category=&start=90
```

(the placement of the keywords parameter could change places with the other parameters)

I would like this to redirect to:

```
URL: http://www.example.com/different_directory/search/keywords/illinois/
```

To achieve this I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   keywords=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^directory1/search/index.php/$  http://www.example.com/different_directory/search/keywords/%1/? [R=301,NC,L]
```

This has not worked out.  Can somebody help me with what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: What does happen when someone goes to the starting URL?

Comment: Nothing.  It does not rewrite the URL at all, and it continues to go to the old URL which is a 404 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is just the trailing forward slash in the pattern of your `RewriteRule`. It should read:

```
^directory1/search/index.php$
```

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Thank you!